# Efficient way of computing running count of "how many x less than y?" in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have 2 sorted lists `x` and `y` and I want to find a running count of how many `x` are less than `y`. The following works for now:

```
x:10*til 3;   / 0 10 20
y:til 30;     / 0 1 2 ... 30
sum {x < y}[;y] each x
q) 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
```

but I suspect using `each` isn't the most efficient way of doing things. Considering my `x`,`y` may end up being in the order of tens of millions of items, is there a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using slaves to perform parallel execution if the function gets too expensive. My example uses 8 slaves.

```
>q -s 8

q)x:10*til 10000
q)y:til 100000
q)\ts sum y>/:x
7200 1312358576
q)\ts sum(y>)peach x
5298 1312424112
q)(sum y>/:x)~sum(y>)peach x
1b
```

Reference: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#peach

Comment: Another approach, given that both lists are sorted: `where deltas(1+y bin x),count y`

Comment: Very nice! (the second suggestion that is). Might even be worth deleting the original response and highlighting this one